# Interesting behaviour when instantiating a class from a DLL

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a reflection project to automatically generate an API. One of the tasks is to generate sample responses, which is a case of taking the return type and just running it through a object generator. Interestingly, though, I've came across a strange issue.

Hopefully I can explain this well enough.

Lets say my generator class is called 'ObjectGenerator'. It takes a type as a parameter, and will attempt to generate a pre-filled class from that type. Here's where the issue arises.

I have an external DLL with fairly efficient error handling, however, on the odd occasion there is the exception on class construction. But the issue is, this will never be caught, regardless of whether I use a try/catch or not. eg:

```
try
{
   object Gen = new ObjectGenerator(someExternalType);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // Some exception occurred when trying to create the object
}
```

When the exception occurs upon creating the object, the try catch will be ignored and an uncaught exception will be raised, causing the system to crash.

This is fairly interesting behaviour, as it doesn't seem off for me to think that the exception could be caught.

Could somebody explain this for me? This doesn't look to be an issue with my code, but more a universal thing, as this has happened on more than one occasion within my code.

EDIT: Looks like this isn't just an external DLL afterall, but more so with any class that uses the ObjectGenerator... hmm - May be bad code.

Comment: can you provide a short *complete* running example of this behaviour?

Comment: What is the uncaught exception that causes crash? In some rare situations (like `StackOverflowException`) the `catch` will not work. I assume it is only your application which crashes, not the entire "system" (operating system)?

Comment: Added it to dropbox. Seems odd: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksoowj1xceq5a6h/ExceptionTest.v12.zip?dl=0

Comment: sorry but I will not download some .zips from dropbox - please add the relevant code to your question - thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zsRE2qQh - http://pastebin.com/LQBnSW2f - http://pastebin.com/JeBKgBLk   - Files too big for comments/edit

Comment: You're expected to provide all information in your question and we shouldn't download external resources to be able to help. Please copy your code and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
try
{
    ObjectGenerator Gen = new ObjectGenerator();
    object obj = Gen.GenerateObject(typeof(Test));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

And the class you're calling:

```
public class Test
{
    public string t;

    public Test()
    {
        t.Split(',');
    }
}
```

It reveals that you call the constructor of `Test`. The constructor accesses the variable `t` which is not initialized. Therefore you get a `NullReferenceException`.

Also, when **in** Visual Studio and debugging, some exceptions get thrown despite an exception handler!

Press CTRL+ALT+E to see what exceptions get thrown anyway when debugging.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. But the fact that the exception doesn't get caught is what I'm a little bit confused by at the present time - It simply states it as an uncaught exception.

Comment: Those could be debugger settings. Try to build it and execute the binary file and it should be caught.

Comment: Yep, running this through the binary works OK and the exception is caught. Odd, I'm interested as to why VS would be behaving in this way. Final code is: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TR5RBG for anybody who is interested (Note that this will not occur on .net fiddle, so you will need to code the code).

Comment: Also on another note, Press CTRL+ALT+E to see what exceptions get thrown anyway when debugging.

Comment: Appreciate your time. +1 and checked answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the system executes the object c'tor **before** it creates the exception frame.

At least this is the only possible explanation that comes to my mind...

Comment: Looks like this may be the case. Code below if you'd like to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksoowj1xceq5a6h/ExceptionTest.v12.zip?dl=0